# How can I plot specifiy function and their foruier transform in matlab

Tags: matlab, math, plot

I have some function I want to plot, calculate fourrier transform then plot fourier transform too, I really don't know how I can achieve this

a couple sample functions:

[image]

or

[image]

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Focus on one thing at a time.  Choose an easy function like sin, create a sample vector x = [-pi:0.1:pi], make y = sin(x), then plot(x, y).  From there you can expand and explore various functions like fft, ifft, zplane, etc.

Comment: and what is a and b ? I realy dont know what is a ,b and how can i intiale them :(

Comment: a and b would be constants in your example.  This isn't a math class though.

Comment: no, my question is about matlab, how plot , and how caculate fourier taransform in matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
  [X,Y] = meshgrid(-4:.2:4, -4:.2:4);
  a=2;b=2;
  Rec = 1/(4*a*b)*(us(a^2-X.^2).*us(b^2-Y.^2));
  surf(X,Y,Rec)
  FftRec=fftshift(fft2(Rec));
  figure;
  imshow(log(FftRec+1));
```

thanks :(

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB will not do that for you. If you want a discrete Fourier transform of a discrete function, you can do that with the `fft` command. MATLAB does have a symbolic toolbox, but it won't handle continuous Fourier transforms. Your best bet is to do this by hand. It's not that complicated. If anything, there are other Stack Exchange sites where your may find better answers concerning the mathematics of this problem. [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) come to mind.